# adding file scan results together

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I have a small program that reads football team scores from a file and only outputs lines that are of valid format. It then adds the goals together and displays a total. How would I go about only displaying results and adding goals only for one team that has been specified by the user?

Here is part of my code:

```
System.out.println("Would you like to generate output in (H)TML or (P)lain text?");
String input = scanner.nextLine();

System.out.println("Select a specific team (<enter> to show all teams):");
String teaminput = scanner.nextLine();

        FileWriter fwriter = new FileWriter("football.html");
        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(fwriter);




        if (input.equalsIgnoreCase("H")){

            writer.write("<html><head><title>Football Scores</title></head><body><h1>Football Scores</h1><table border=\"1\">");
            writer.write("<th>Team 1</th><th>Team 2</th><th>Team 1 Score</th><th>Team 2 Score</th>");
            while (fileScan.hasNextLine()){
            String line = null;

            line = fileScan.nextLine();
            String[] element = line.split (":");

                if(line.matches("\\w+?\\s?\\w+?\\s?\\w+?\\s?[:]\\s?\\w+?\\s?\\w+?\\s?\\w+?\\s?[:]\\s?\\d+?\\s?[:]\\s?\\d+?")){ //regex pattern used to only accept valid lines. 
                       count++;
                       writer.write("<tr><td>"+element[0]+"</td><td>"+element[2]+"</td><td>"+element[1]+"</td><td>"+element[3]+"</td></tr>"); //creating output format for the strings to be printed


                       sum += Integer.parseInt(element[2].trim()); 
                       sum1 += Integer.parseInt(element[3].trim());

                } else {
                invalidLines++;
                }

        }
            writer.write(result = sum + sum1);
            writer.write("<br>Total number of goals: " +result);
            writer.write("<br>"+count+" lines successfully validated");
            writer.write("<br>"+invalidLines+" lines declined.");
            writer.write("</table></body></html>");
            writer.close();
```

Here's example input data:

```
Leeds United : Liverpool : 1 : 2
Chelsea :  Manchester City : 1 : 1
Aston Villa : Middlesbrough : 3 : 1
```

Comment: And your question? You input file sample contents?

Comment: I've added sample data, Question is already there.

Comment: And you don't know how to compare Strings, or what? Just compare `teaminput` with `element[0]` or `element[1]`.

Comment: Code is not compileable, question is not there.. am afraid anyone without these could help!

Comment: Code is not compileable because as stated its just part of the code I'm working on, Question on the other hand is as I've mentioned up top:  "How would I go about only displaying results and adding goals only for one team that has been specified by the user?", When I compare strings using .matches() it always returns false.

Comment: When do some research and find the difference between `matches` and the correct method for comparing Strings.